# webpack.prod.config.js loader section for scss

Tags: webpack, sass

My dev loader configuration for sass is as follows:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',

      // Could also be write as follow:
      // use: 'css-loader?modules&importLoader=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader'
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          query: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            importLoaders: 2,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
```

What should it be for `webpack.prod.config.js`?  I am using css modules and I want to minify.  Does this look correct and do I need the `lodalIdentName` in production:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',

      // Could also be write as follow:
      // use: 'css-loader?modules&importLoader=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!sass-loader'
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            minimize: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep only the hash in `localIdentName`, and remove source map